# Using Full text search on varbinary data type for searching file contents

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

I create a full-text search index on varbinary(max) column and insert file content into this column.(files like docx,xlsx,txt,...) I create an extension column for specify content type.but when I query this table with contains,

```
    SELECT *
    FROM tblFiles
    WHERE CONTAINS(tblFiles.FileContent, 'web OR webserver');
```

no result were showing.why?

Comment: What does your schema look like? How did you create the fulltext index? How big is your table? How long did you wait after creating the index before testing your query?

Comment: I first create a catalog for my database and create full text index by right clicking on table and select full-text index and select define Full-Text index.I didn't wait after creating the index.why I should wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why my query dont work. because files that inserted into db was docx and in my database does not exist any filter for this format.I inserted a doc document and query it.It works. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait a bit after defining a full text index, because the index itself is created in the background; it's an async process, not synchronous. For a small table it may not be noticeable, but for a large one, it will be.

Also, make sure the types in your file type column start with a dot: `.docx` instead of just `docx`.